# Prevent reset password specific user role

Tags: filters, password

I have user role "b2b_account". I want to prevent user who have role b2b_account to reset their password.

Here my code

```
add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', 'filter_function_name_2698', 10, 2 );
    function filter_function_name_2698( $allow, $ID ){

        $users = get_users(array(
            'role' => 'b2b_account',
        ));
        foreach($users as $user){
            if($user->ID){

                return false;

                }
            }
    }
```

I use filter allow_password_reset, but it prevent all user.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know the filter, but you probably just need to `return true` if you don't find the user. (And possibly abort immediately if $allow is false?) However there must be better ways of doing this, e.g. look up the user ID we have and see what roles it has rather than fetching all users in the role?

Comment: Oh, you're also just testing if $user->ID has a value. You're not testing it against $ID

Comment: Would it work to prevent them from changing their profile altogether? Or do you need to limit it to only password changes?

Comment: @JoshM I only prevent when password change only. tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are

- you're testing `if($user->ID){`, i.e. does the b2b_account user object we've found have an ID. Which it always will. You probably meant to compare it to `$ID`.
- you need to `return true` in the success case, i.e. after your for loop if you didn't find the user.

However

- you're ignoring the `$allow` parameter. You could end with `return $allow` instead, but it would make more sense to not even do the restricted group check if a previous filter left `$allow = false` or returned a WP_Error
- it would make more sense to me to fetch the current groups for the user and see if b2b_account is included, rather than fetch all b2b_account users and check against that list of IDs.

So I'd suggest

```
add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', 'filter_function_name_2698', 10, 2 );
function filter_function_name_2698( $allow, $ID ) {
    if ( ( ! $allow ) || is_wp_error( $allow ) ) {
         // Rejected by a previous filter
         return $allow;
    }

    // Read the user's roles
    $user_data = get_userdata( $ID );
    if ( $user_data ) {
        $user_roles = $user_data->roles;

        if ( $user_roles && in_array( 'b2b_account', $user_roles, true ) ) {
            // b2b_accounts may not reset passwords
            return false;
        }
    }
    // else user doesn't exist

    return true;
}
```

(using the role check code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719421/243245), plus an extra probably-not-necessary null check)

Comment: thanks's this is works